# Saving an input into InfoWindow entered by a user on a marker/pin

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to implement a program where a user enter a description in the info window which pop ups when you click on a marker/pin(previously inserted by user upon clicking). Now code works fine and a textfield appears on an infowindow and takes text as an input but the problem is when i close that text field and click on the same marker again it looses it content which was last entered. Below is the code i wrote with the help of an expert on this forum.
P.S: I am trying to learn javascript an i am new so if this question is below belt i apologize.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Accessing arguments in UI events</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(65.0126304,25.4703071)
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
  });
}

function placeMarker(position, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map
  });
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content : "<input type='text'>"
});

  map.panTo(position);
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, "click", function() {
   infowindow.open( map, marker );
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way:

1. Define a global counter which increases after each marker was added,
2. Give current value of that counter to infowindow so that, we can use it to give an id to inputs and make sure they are unique,
3. Add an event `closeclick` to infowindows that updates the input content with the filled information when infowindows are being closed.
4. Increment `index` after these.

**Solution**

1- Place `index = 0;` before `function initialize() {`

2- Update your infowindow creator with this:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content : "<input id='myText" + index + "' type='text'>",
    id : index
});
```

3- Add another event after marker click event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener( infowindow, "closeclick", function(e) {
    infowindow.setContent("<input id='myText" + infowindow.id + "' type='text' value='" + document.getElementById("myText" + infowindow.id).value + "'>");
});
```

4- Add `index++;` after `closeclick` event.

This may not be the best practice but it should work.

Comment: It took me some time to implement it(not a smart person at all). Thanks a lot for the help really.